# How to check if an android device is equipped with a wifi adapter?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

Of course the **vast majority** of android devices support wifi but not all of them.

How could someone check to see if the **wifi is supported** on the **current device**?
For instance with bluetooth you could just do (in Scala):

```
def isBluetoothSupported: Boolean = {
  BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter match {
    case null => false;
    case x: BluetoothAdapter => true;
  }
}
```

What is the corresponding code for wifi?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know Scala, but the relevant API call is:

```
getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_WIFI)
```

The above would allow you to detect whether wifi is available at runtime.

While not directly relevant to your question, another option that might be of use is the ["uses-feature" tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) element.  Adding something like the following to your manifest would [filter your application out on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#declared) for devices without wifi:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
```

Comment: Wifi functionality is optional on my app but thanks for pointing this out! I guess the method `hasSystemFeature` is a generic way to check all kind of hardware. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the system services.

```
if( Context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) == NULL)
{
    //Service name doesn't exist
}
else
{
    //Service Exists
}
```